# Unity3d multiplayer canvas

Tags: unity, unity-networking

so I am making multiplayer game and I stuck on one thing, I have blood overlay canvas in my scene(you know, in fps games if somebody shoots you your screen becomes red and this stuff), and when I shoot enemy, his screen becomes red, but mine also.

thats what i ahve now: if raycast hits enemy, player script calls: `ColorController.MakeItred();` color controller is attached to this canvas image, here is its code:

`

```
 void Start () {
       if (current == 100 || current == 0)
        {
        opacity = 0;
        }
    }


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
          image = GetComponent<Image>();
    image.color = new Color32(reds, greens, blues, opacity);

    if (current == 0)
    {
        opacity = 0;
    }
    if (!playing)
    {
        if (opacity > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(toLower());
        }
        }
    if (opacity == 255)
    {
        playaudio();

    }

}

public static void MakeItred()
{
    opacity = 255;

}
public static void MakeItOff()
{
    opacity = 0;

}
 void playaudio()
{
    AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.Play();
}
private IEnumerator toLower()
{
    playing = true;
    opacity -= 1;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    playing = false;
}`
```

btw thats function in player code that calls *colorcontroller.makeitred*,

`[ClientRpc]
    public void Rpcdoit()
    {
        ColorController.MakeItred();
    }`

-Nick
thanks.

Comment: There could be a million reason why this happens. To diagnose the problem we would need to know how you implemented the triggering of the screen overlay effect and your networking. But you aren't posting anything about this, so unfortunately this question can not be answered.

Comment: @Philipp yes, I will add details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You method `makeItRed` is a `static` method which sets a variable which is most likely also declared as `static`. Static variables share their value between all instances of the class. Call the method on one instance of `ColorController` and you affect them all.

So make `opacity`, `MakeItred` and `MakeItOff` non-static variables and have the raycast hit code (which you did not post) call `GetComponent<ColorController>().MakeItred()` on the object where the raycast-hit was successful.

Also, the ColorController component should check if the `gameObject` it is assigned to is the local player and only then affect the overlay graphic.